# Mapping IDictionary<Entity, Component> with MappingByCode

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

How can I map `IDictionary<Entity, Component>`? I've done this way:

```
Map<GeneralResourceType, Quantity>(x => x.BookedResources,
c =>
    {
        c.Key(ck => ck.Column("ProposedAction"));
        c.Table("BookedResources");
    },
k => k.ManyToMany(key => key.Column("ResourceTypeId")),
r => r.Component(qc => QuantityMapping.Mapping()));
```

(where GeneralResourceType is a mapped Entity and Quantity is a ValueObject). But during the call of BuildSession() exception is thrown:

NHibernate.MappingException : An association from the table BookedResources refers to an unmapped class: {MyNamespace}.Quantity.
Seams like it tries to find ClassMapping for Quantity, while value part mapped as Component.

Comment: what if you leave out `r => r.Component(qc => QuantityMapping.Mapping())`?

Comment: The same exception is thrown. Thanks for try though, cause i have no more ideas how I can fix this...

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

- First variant:

  1. Map component in separate class inherited from ComponentMapping generic class.
  2. Map dictionary property as follows:

     ```
     Map(x => x.BookedResources, c =>
     {
         //any options access, cascade etc
     });
     ```
- Second variant (inline):

  ```
  Map(x => x.BookedResources, x =>
      {
          //any options access, cascade etc
      },
      x => x.Element(),
      x => x.Component(c =>
      {
          c.Class<Quantity>();
          c.Property(p => p.Amount);
          c.Property(p => p.Unit);
          // any other properties
      }
  ));
  ```